# Why do I get the error: "cannot communicate with the debug host process" when attempting to execute an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

I create a new package in SSIS and when I try to run the package, SSIS returns the following error (displayed in a Visual Studio Error Dialog):

> Cannot communicate with the debug host process. The IDtsHost interface is not registered.
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration"

Environment:  VS 2019 with newest SSIS Extension Installed.  The package appears to be created correctly and the build succeeds.

The error happens even if the package is trivial "hello world" type of package.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in this case was the selected targeted version of SQL Server. My project was configured to target "SQL Server 2017", but was connected to a server running SQL Server 2012.

If you're seeing this error, this may be the reason. Here are the steps to change this:

1. Go to the properties page of the Integration Services project that contains the affected package (right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Properties)
2. In the Property Pages dialog, navigate to Configuration Properties > General.
3. Under the property group **Deployment Target Version**, for the TargetServerVersion property, select the SQL Server version that matches the one you're connecting to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, lowering the SQL Server's version (to match mine) in the "TargetServerVersion" property resolved this.  I had to also disable / select "False" for "AzureEnable" feature in order to do this though.

Comment: This did not work for me--I am targeting a SQL Server 2016 environment and my `TargetServerVersion` is set to `SQL Server 2016`. My `AzureEnable` option is also already set to `False`. I am running SQL Server Integration Services Projects version 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this as well in VS2019 SSDT. In my case it was a working SSIS package that after going to sleep for the night, the machine woke up and wouldn't execute the same scripts. These were my steps:

1. Open each connection within the script, Test Connection and Save
2. Clean the solution
3. Rebuild the solution

Answer (score 2):

Working through an [SSIS tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/sql-server-integration-services-2) using SQL Server 2019 Developer (v15.0.2080.9) and VS2019 Community (v16.11.9) to create packages using SSDT ([SSIS Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) v3.15).

Packages in VS have executed without issue in the past. *I then upgraded my machine from Windows 10 Pro to 11.* Now, when running the same - possibly any - package I get the following error:

```
===================================

Failed to start project (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

Cannot create a debug host for the package. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(Boolean isRemoteTest, IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32 launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32 launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

===================================

Cannot communicate with the debug host process. The IDtsHost interface is not registered. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.DebugEngine.LaunchDtsDebugHost(Process& process, Boolean run64bit)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.DtsProgramNode.CreateRuntimePackageInternal(IDtsHost& host, Process& process, Package& dtsPackage)
```

...and the package does not execute.

### My Solution

I then chose to repair my SQL Server installation instead of re-installing. This was accomplished via the SQL Server Installation Center > Maintenance > Repair option. In my case, I chose the default instance, MSSQLSERVER.

*VS now runs without the error and successfully executes the package.*

I couldn't say whether my solution was solely based on the repaired SQL Server instance or a combination of other things tried *and* my last action. So I offer the path I took in the case of the latter.

Aside: The other choices during the SQL Server repair on my system were (1) another server instance, SQLSERVER2019, and (2) "shared components". Selecting either of those *may* have resolved the issue as well, but I couldn't confirm that.

Comment: I received the same error, but when I click Repair, I had to download the install source so I did so from here (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads?rtc=1) and I got an error doing the LocalDB install (An installation package for the product Microsoft SQL Server 2019 LocalDB  cannot be found) but it did resovle the issue.

Comment: I ran into this while completing Lesson 5 of this training (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-5-4-testing-the-lesson-5-tutorial-package?view=sql-server-ver16) with the new tooling running on VS 2022 Enterprise and SQL Server 2022 Developer (x64).

The error I was seeing was "Cannot create a debug host for the package. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)"

The SQL Server Repair addressed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

In Project Property, turn off Azure-Enabled as seen in the image below. Your package will execute afterwards.

[image]

Comment: "*Your package will execute afterwards.*" Incorrect. `AzureEnabled` was set to False for me already and yet I'm having this problem.